# Is there a way to get Google Calendar to hide duplicate events?

Tags: google-calendar

I subscribe to the calendars of my team members, but if I invite all of them to a meeting, my calendar fills up with entries for each of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google never added this capability to it's "calendar" (classic version as of fall 2017); however, there is a Google Chrome plugin that partially accomplishes this.

[Event Merge for Google Calendar™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep?hl=en) works when viewing via Google Chrome browser on desktop or laptop.  It does not actually remove the event from each separate calendar that you may be viewing/following.  Nor does this apply to the calendar view built into an Android or iOS device.

[image: Event Merge for Google Calendar preview]

Otherwise, refer to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/bOSfyMmWIRc/2iDR10NvBhoJ for a history of the request for this feature with Google product support.

Comment: Rats.  Thanks for the clear and authoritative answer -- with references even!